# Is there anyway to assign an index to a control in the WinForms or WPF designer?

Tags: .net, user-interface, controls, indexing

I remember VB5 (and all the horrors in it), but one thing I liked about it was that I could set an index on a control in the properties window in the designer. Are there any way to do something like this in WinForms, the WPF designer or XAML ?

Comment: Like a TabIndex, or the actual order of the element in a list of elements?

Comment: Well, the order. But any kind of indexing would be nice, allowing me to create (for example) an array of buttons..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The control arrays from pre-.NET VB are not around anylonger. You can simulate it manually though, by declaring an array of the Control type in question, and populating it with the control instances when the form is created.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I was afraid of. Populating at runtime it just not that great an option :) Thanks anyway..